# model doesn't display title Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In the admin the content of my model doesn't show a title, now I now that I can make a field called title but then I need it to be an incrementing int, but if I do that Django tells me that that can't happen because it will get rid of the ID, is there anyway I can fix this?

model:

```
class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(albums, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    review = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

[how the admin looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqNm0.png)

if there is any information missing please let me know

Comment: Please share also your admin.py. Are you sure, that you have the subject in the object?

Comment: I found out that the problem wasn't with the admin or anything like that, but that the subject didn't get saved, that's also why it didn't show up as a title for the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide something like that for displaying the ID of your model when subject is empty:

```py
class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(albums, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    review = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject or f"ReviewRating #{self.pk}"
```

You can replace f-string by a translation if you want

Comment: @Narton you can mark answer as resolved if it is ok